# Rails Admin - STI Models not showing up in list on edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, sti

I have a subject model which has many details

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :details, inverse_of: :main_subject, foreign_key: :main_subject_id
end


class Detail
  TYPES = %w(article book event product short_course slide_share video website).freeze
  CLASS_TYPES = TYPES.map { |type| "Detail::#{type.camelize}" }.freeze

  belongs_to :main_subject, inverse_of: :details, class_name: Subject
  enum difficulty: { easy: 1, medium: 2, hard: 3 }

  rails_admin do
    list do
      field :name do
        queryable true
      end

      field :difficulty do
        queryable false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There are multiple type of details available in application so I have

```
class Detail::Article < Detail; end
class Detail::Website < Detail; end
class Detail::Video < Detail; end
```

When I go to edit Subject panel my list for details is empty (the right one with assigned details correctly shows all associated details), and I cannot find a way to make rails_admin fill it with all available details. I've checked on the github and here, but cannot find any viable solution. Is it rails_admin bug that it doesn't show up STI models in these list or am I missing some kind of config?

[image: screenshot from rails_admin]

*the list on the left is empty despite over 200 details available in db, the right one shows nothing because nothing is associated (I've removed associated details, and reloaded page - now cannot even bring those back)*

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: not sure if this is related, but why did you do `belongs_to :main_subject`, and `inverse_of :subject`, shouldn't the two be the same ?

Comment: thanks, I've mistakenly wrongly copied the code - I've updated this - but it is not related to the problem

Comment: does `Detail.all` return all details of all types in rails console ?

Comment: yes, `[1] pry(main)> Detail.all.size # => 240`

Comment: wait does the list start to return objects when you type? in the search box

Comment: when I try to filter the details list on subject edit page? Nothing on the page, PG errors in the console -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/10321355/, full stacktrace: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10321369/, it doesn't return any objects

Comment: could you add the difficulty part in the detail model, cause it seems to be the problem, so it might be defined in a wrong way

Comment: it's enum, added it to the code, it is integer, and it's working correctly across the application

Comment: try `enum difficulty: %i(easy medium hard)` and make sure the data type is integer in the database

Comment: updated the code with new rails_admin config for the detail model - I've added rails config to ommit difficulty, now when I type anything into the field above the list it actually fills the list with something, but still without typing anything it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rails admin doesn't show records by default if they are > 100, when you start typing it starts populating, I found out that if you want to show all, you could search for `%` which will return all from the query.
From the [wiki page](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping#scoping-ordering-and-limiting-associable-records-in-filtering-selectsmultiselects) it says you could add this line if you want it to be pre-populated with all records

```
field :details do
  associated_collection_cache_all true
end
```

PS: make sure you don't add this block inside the `list` scope, add it either inside `edit` or in the root scope like they did in their example

Comment: thanks a lot, setting difficulty in detail to not be queryable and adding config you provided solved the problem :)